# Using code from ipython in Rstudio

Tags: r, google-bigquery, ipython

I am trying to CLV in R using data from Big Query. 
I have found an article describing how to do it, but the guide codes in iPython instead of, which I not familiar with.

(The guide I want to use: https://github.com/googleanalytics/bigquery-export-ipython-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/customer-base-analysis.ipynb)

**My question is:** 
- Why would you run R code in iPython and not in Rstudio?
- What code do I have to change in order to run the same analysis in Rstudio instead?

Comment: The reason why is probably to be able to use the library [BTYD](http://cran.r-project.org/package=BTYD) while still using tools available in Python (such as building notebooks that renders HTML). Still, migrating to pure R code shouldn't be a problem as all you'd need is using [BigQuery R](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) connector's to retrieve the data instead of Python's. The rest would be just the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have got most of it to work, but I can't figure out how to import the data back into Bigquery from Rstudio. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The connector should already do the trick. The [official docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/bigrquery.pdf) might guide you on how you want to run this operation.